# How to get the current date and time after a user select action

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I spent time learning Rails and now I'm working on a demo project.

I want the user to select whether or not they need immediate care on a care request _form.  If the user selects "No" then the user will be asked to  select a time and date from the next two hidden lines of code, saving `start_time` and `start_date`. If the user selects "Yes",  I want to pass in  the current time and date for the `start_time` and `start_date` fields after the user clicks the submit button on my form.

I know I will use an `if`/`else` statement, a hidden function, and the `Time.now`/`DateTime.now`  methods but I'm confused how to implement them.

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label">Is immediate care needed?</label>
      <select class="form-control edit">
        <option>Yes</option>
        <option>No</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>


<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Choose your start date.</label>
    <%= f.text_field :start_day, placeholder: "MM/DD/YY", class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Choose your start time.</label>
    <%= f.text_field :start_time, placeholder: "08:00 AM", class: " form-control" %>
  </div>
</div>
```

I looked at Stack Overflow but found nothing similar to this.

Comment: So I'm not entirely sure I follow what you are asking, but if I do, can you just have the divs with the 'optional' content set to be hidden and have an on click handler for the initial input that toggles visibility based on the value of the select?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am trying to do, but I also want to get the current time  and date  for my start_time and start_date fields, only  if the user selects yes for immediate care. @jaydel

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to name your "immediate care" select field, and supply values for options:

```
<select class="form-control edit" name="immediate_care">    
  <option value="yes">Yes</option>
  <option value="no">No</option>
</select>
```

Then, you need to check the selected value and set current date & time values if the value is "yes" (maybe a before_filter inside a controller):

```
if params[:immediate_care] == 'yes'
  current_time = Time.now
  params[:start_time] = current_time.strftime '%l:%m %p'
  params[:start_day] = current_time.strftime '%d/%m/%y'
end
```

Please keep in mind, that's a simplified example, since you did not provide more details about your code.

Comment: I had another answer in the works, but I think this is the right one. One of the key points here is that you've got your business logic where it belongs: NOT on the view. Parameter management is the duty of the controller.

Comment: Thats not gonna send params to controller... U have to use `select_tag` -> http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag

Comment: Using `select_tag` is just using a helper to render form. That has nothing to do with sending data to controller :)

Comment: Thank you @siemakuba: !!!  That solved 1/2 of my problems.I was also having trouble keeping the last two text fields hidden unless "no" has been selected by the user.

Comment: if params[:immediate_care] == 'yes'
  current_time = Time.now
  params[:start_time] = current_time.strftime '%l:%m %p'
  params[:start_day] = current_time.strftime '%d/%m/%y'
end

Comment: @CoreyShaw I think that's a subject for a new question :)