# How to keep specific text fields hidden until a user selects an action that complies with that specific field(s)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

I spent time learning Rails and now I'm working on a demo project.The first thing I want the user to do, is to select whether or not they need immediate care on a care request _form.                                                   If the user selects "false" then the user will be asked to select a time and date from the next two hidden lines of code, passing in my start_time and start_date.                                                                    If the user selects "true", I want to use Time.now to get the current time and current date for my start_time and start_date fields when the user clicks the submit button on the request _form.                                             My question is What is the proper way to keep the last two fields hidden until a user selects "false"?                                                    requests_form.html.erb

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
     <%= f.check_box :immediate_care,{:checked => "checked"} %> Patient needs immediate care.
    </div
 </div>   

<div class="row">
   <div class="form-group">
       <label>Choose your start date.</label>
       <%= f.text_field :start_day, placeholder: "MM/DD/YY", class: "form control" %>
       </div>
 </div>

<div class="row">
   <div class="form-group">
      <label>Choose your start time.</label>
      <%= f.text_field :start_time, placeholder: "08:00 AM", class: " form-control" %>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: First, please limit your questions to a single question per post. `Time.now` is a separate issue and should be asked in a separate question. Second, what control is the user using? A select or radio buttons or what?

Comment: Agreed. Please note that this question was spawned off http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38960667/how-to-get-the-current-date-and-time-after-a-user-select-action as a way to address the first question here as a separate one. The second question is/can be addressed in that other question.

Comment: Ok, thank you @MarsAtomic  and jaydel for informing me.I'm new to StackOverFlow and still adapting to the rules. I've now made the proper adjustments to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a drastically simplified solution. The basic idea is that you wrap the optionally displayed input fields inside a single div. You defined a couple CSS classes that will show and hide that div respectively. You bind a javascript function to the click event on that select that will add and remove the CSS classes to the optional div depending upon the select:option value.

The HTML:

```
<select id='my_select'>Do you want Immediate Care?
  <option value='yes'>Yes</option> 
  <option value='no'>No</option>
</select>

<div class='reveal' id='date_fields'>
  ... in here you put the fields you want to hide and show ...
</div>
```

The Javascript:

```
$document.ready(function() {
  $('#my_select').bind('click', function() {
    selected_option = $('#my_select option:selected');
    if $(selected_option).val() == 'yes' {
      $('#date_fields').addClass('reveal');
      $('#date_fields').removeClass('hide');
    } else {
      $('#date_fields').addClass('hide');
      $('#date_fields').removeClass('reveal');
    }
  });
});
```

And finally, the CSS:

```
.reveal {
  display: block;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

I candidly admit that in places my syntax might be off. As a Rails developer I've opted to use Coffeescript and SASS so my Javascript and SASS syntax skills have atrophied a bit over the last 5 years. Please feel free to point out issues and/or edit fixes in.

A few caveats to this. Since divs display:block by default, you can use a single CSS class that changes that to display:none and have the click handler simply add and remove that one class. I made my example more explicit so it's easier to follow the logic.

Also, I may have bound the click incorrectly. Again, this example is just to show the general approach to the problem that I would take.

Answer (score 0):

Add class for optional fields wrappers:

```
<div class="row optional">
```

Add this script:

```
<script>
  $('#patient_immediate_care').change(function() {
      if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $('.optional').hide();
      }
      else {
        $('.optional').show();
      }
    }

  );
  $(function() {
      if($('#name_immediate_care').is(":checked")) {
        $('.optional').hide();
      }
      else {
        $('.optional').show();
      }
  });
</script>
```

And css:

```
<style>
    .optional {
      display: none;
    }
</style>
```

Check ids of yor form elements. It depends on `form_for`. patient is for example.

Comment: This works! But only when I uncheck and check the box .Also, If I refresh the page then the fields are visible again. –

Comment: I've edited post to hide fields by default because default value is checked and add script to show/hide optional fields after refresh.